# How can I sort this Collection using an array order?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

How can I sort the $item type based on the order? This is what I currently have:

```
$order = ['AA', 'zl', 'Dr', 'co', 'og'];

$items->sort(
    function ($a, $b) use ($order) {
        return strcmp($b->type, $a->type) // how do I apply the order here?
            ?: strcmp($b->date, $a->date);
    }
);
```

Basically it's a two column sort where it first sorts by type and then sorts by date. The type would be sorted using the array order rather than the typical alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare the keys in `$order` corresponding to the type of each item.

```
    return ($order[$b->type] - $order[$a->type]) 
           ?: strcmp($b->date, $a->date);
```

This should work if all of your items have types contained in `$order`. If not, you'll get undefined index errors which will mess up the sort. But since you haven't specified how items like that should be sorted in your question, I'm assuming that they all do.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you